# Laravel, copy row to another table with eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to get the data form database table and create a new row in another table.
Which 1 PO have many PoProducts.

```
    $_getPO = Order::find($id);
    $_getPOProducts= OrderProducts::where('order_id', $id)->get();

    $order_no = $_getPO->order_no;
    $eta = $_getPO->eta;

    $_Order = new DeliveryOrders();
    $_Order->order_no = $order_no;
    $_Order->eta = $eta;
    $_Order->save();

    $POProduct = array();
    foreach($_getPOProducts as $i => $_getPOProduct)
    {
        $POProduct[] = new DeliveryOrderProducts();
        $POProduct[] = $_getPOProduct->order_id;
        $POProduct[] = $_getPOProduct->item_id;
        $POProduct[] = $_getPOProduct->qty;
        $POProduct->save();
    }
```

But, this output an error.

```
   Call to a member function save() on array
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: The save() method is used on a Eloquent model which you've not created. You created the $POProduct as an array when I most likely should be a model by the same name. Do you have a Model object by the same name?

Comment: I don't think i have, but how to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to run the `save` method on the array but what you want is to use it on the array index instead.

Change your `foreach` to this and it should work (assuming columns are the same).

```
foreach($_getPOProducts as $i => $_getPOProduct)
{
    $POProduct[$i] = new DeliveryOrderProducts();
    $POProduct[$i]->order_id = $_getPOProduct->order_id;
    $POProduct[$i]->item_id = $_getPOProduct->item_id;
    $POProduct[$i]->qty = $_getPOProduct->qty;
    $POProduct[$i]->save();
}
```

You can shorten this by using `forceCreate`.

```
foreach($_getPOProducts as $i => $_getPOProduct)
{
    $POProduct[$i] = (new DeliveryOrderProducts())->forceCreate($_getPOProduct->only(['order_id', 'item_id', 'qty']));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to copy records from one table to another or just duplicate a record in the same table you could simply use the `repliacate()` method.

```
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        
        // replicate (duplicate) the data
        $staff = $user->replicate();

        // make into array for mass assign. 
        //make sure you activate $guarded in your Staff model
        $staff = $staff->toArray();

        Staff::firstOrCreate($staff);
```

Note: in case you're only duplicating on the same table replace `Staff` with `User` on this example.